# Function that returns the invocation of its first parameter

Tags: javascript

On an array of functions, I essentially want to be able to run them all.

Kind of like this, **functionArray.map(call)**.

Is there any simple way to do this within JavaScript or Lodash other than the obvious (below)

---

```
functionArray.map(fn => fn())
```

Not all browsers support this yet

---

```
functionArray.map(function(fn) { return fn(); })
```

This is longer than it needs to be

---

```
function call(fn) { return fn(); })
```

defining a this function every time you want to use it, this seems like a silly solution, so a problem that might already be defined

Comment: There is no shortcut here. You have to do it the second way, it's the shortest unless you can depend on `=>` working, which you can't in the browser.

Comment: The second option isn't longer than it needs to be, it is as short as it can be without using the arrow syntax. Unless you want to save two characters by using a single-letter argument name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the 3rd option is your best bet:

```
function callSelf(fn) { return fn(); }
functionArray.map(callSelf)
```